# kibana not accessible with message "Please, upgrade your browser" from Chrome 105

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

after upgrade to ELK 8.2.2 I can not access KIBANA from Chrome (  Chrome is up to dateVersion 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)  ) , it is showing me the message: "Please, upgrade your browser" , anybody has an idea how to solve this?

( I dont have this problem from Edge from same computer ...   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kibana shows this message if a browser doesn't support content-security-policy 305.

Do you have a proxy in front of Kibana that could affect set CSP headers?
Do you have any error messages in the browser console? Try opening your browser's dev tools and report what you see. In the normal case with Chrome you should see:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-dfwkrmf3eoeeUSOe5V/dede2c+yeadce32Oi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Comment: There is no proxy , but also the strange thing is that from another computer with same browser version the issue do not appear and I cannot find what is different ...

Comment: were you able to find any error on browser's dev tools? you can hit the console tab from the inspect element option of browser.

Comment: I succeeded to fix via setting from kibana  csp.strict: fasle to disable csp so I accept your answer since it helped me figuring out the  option further.